# why promql expression {__name__=~ ".*"} results in error message

Tags: prometheus, promql

prometheus promql expression `{__name__ =~ ".*"}` fails with error below where as `{__name__ =~ ".+"}` is valid query (regular expression .* vs .+)

```
Error executing query: invalid parameter "query": 1:1: parse error: vector selector must contain at least one non-empty matcher
```

Comment: Although I have not experienced this problem and now I can't test it, but based on the error message, `.+` may work because it expects at least one character or more, while `.*` expects zero character or more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In promql expression, it is mandatory to provide at least one non-empty label value as selector to match. The regular expression in the selector ".*' includes empty string which is the root cause of this error. However, ".+" doesn't include empty string and hence satisfies the condition at least one non-empty label value for selector.

Why prometheus has to fail if the selector RE expansion includes an empty string, is something not very clear (why this restriction from prometheus)? (Vector selector `__name__=".*"` should not be considered as empty selector as it has many non-empty strings as well)

One answer little bit convincing is prometheus doesn't store any empty label values. empty labels like `name=""` is same as label `name` not present at all in prometheus.

PromQL regular expressions follow [RE2 syntax](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) where

. means any character

".*" means zero or more occurrence of any character.

".+" means one or more occurrence of any character.

More details in attachment.
[image]

Comment: I don't see how you think RE2 is related to problem you encountered, and why it is needed to be mentioned in answer. Also, [please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). You already have a link to screenshoted page: use citation instead.

Comment: It is related as the regular expression in the error case expands to include empty string which results in voilating the rule "at least one label matcher that does not match the empty string". This I wanted to explain using the rules of RE2. I agree screenshots are not good but I want to help reader pointing to the lines referred in the question (not going through the entire page).

Answer (score 1):

This is [documented](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#instant-vector-selectors) limitation of promQL.

> Vector selectors must either specify a name or at least one label matcher that does not match the empty string. The following expression is illegal:
>
> ```
> {job=~".*"} # Bad!
> ```
>
> In contrast, these expressions are valid as they both have a selector that does not match empty label values.
>
> ```
> {job=~".+"}              # Good!
> {job=~".*",method="get"} # Good!
> ```

Additionally, I'd like to point out that `{name=~".*"}` would match (if it worked) any metric, as non-existing labels are equivalent to empty strings, and would be matched by `.*`. `{name=~".+"}` in turn will match all metrics with label `name` and is equivalent to `{name!=""}`. [Here](https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/graph?g0.expr=%7B__name__%3D%22up%22%2C%20env%3D%7E%22.*%22%7D&g0.tab=1&g0.stacked=0&g0.range_input=1h&g1.expr=%7B__name__%3D%22up%22%2C%20env%3D%7E%22.%2B%22%7D&g1.tab=1&g1.stacked=0&g1.range_input=1h&g2.expr=%7B__name__%3D%22up%22%2C%20env!%3D%22%22%7D&g2.tab=1&g2.stacked=0&g2.range_input=1h) is demo of similar queries that shows described effect.